# Can CouchDB actually be used for a desktop application?

Tags: couchdb, desktop-application

I'm hoping someone can validate or correct my conclusions here.

I'm looking into writing a small side project. I want to create a desktop application for taking notes that will synchronise to a web-server so that multiple installations can be kept in step and data shared and also so that it can be accessed via a browser if necessary.

I've kind of been half-listening to the noises about CouchDB and I've heard mention of "offline functionality", of desktop-couchdb and of moves to utilise its ability to handle intermittent communications to enable distributed applications in the mobile market. This all led me to believe that it might be an interesting option to look at for providing my data storage and also handling my synchronisation needs, but after spending some time looking around for info on how to get started my conclusion is that I've got completely the wrong end of the stick and the reality is that:

*There's no way of packaging up a CouchDB instance, distributing it as part of a desktop application and running it in the context of that application to provide local storage and synchronisation to a central database.*

Am I correct here? If so is there any technology out there that does this sort of thing or am I left just rolling my own local storage and maybe still using CouchDB on the server?

Comment: At least one person decided that the answer was no: http://philwilson.org/blog/2009/04/couchdb-in-desktop-applications

Comment: But then there's the desktopcouch effort over at Ubuntu: https://launchpad.net/desktopcouch 
It appears to be *nix-only at this point. More interesting docs are here: http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/desktopcouch

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update (2012/05)**: check out the new TouchDB projects from Couchbase if you are targeting [Mac OS X and/or iOS](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/TouchDB-iOS) or [Android](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/TouchDB-Android). These actually use SQLite under the hood (at least for now) but can replicate to/from a "real" CouchDB server. Another clientside alternative that is finally starting to mature is [PouchDB](https://github.com/mikeal/pouchdb/), which runs in IndexedDB capable browser engines. Using these or using them to inspire similar port to another desktop platform is now becoming a better-trod path.

*Original answer:*

> There's no way of packaging up a
>   CouchDB instance, distributing it as
>   part of a desktop application and
>   running it in the context of that
>   application to provide local storage
>   and synchronisation to a central
>   database.

At this point in time, your statement is practically correct although it is possible to include CouchDB in an app — for an example see CouchDBX.app which is a thin wrapper around a prefixed bundle of CouchDB and all its dependencies.

The easiest way to build a CouchDB app is to assume that the user will already have [a CouchDB server](http://www.couchone.com/get) running. This is easier than it sounds, especially with Couchone's hosting or a prebuilt app like CouchDBX on OS X or DesktopCouch on Ubuntu. This latter is especially interesting, because if I understand correctly it is included by default with Ubuntu these days, and automatically spins up a CouchDB server per-user when you query its port via D-Bus. Something similar could (and should) be done on OS X using launchd and Bonjour.

So as you write, you either would design your app to store data in a local format and optionally sync with a CouchDB service you provide or you'd have to [build](https://github.com/couchone/build-couchdb) and bundle all of Erlang, SpiderMonkey and CouchDB together with your app along with some scripts to make sure it was running when needed. This is possible but obviously neither of these are ideal, and believe me you're not the only one wanting a simpler solution for desktop-oriented apps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer (and to the commenters). I had imagined something like an SQLite local store and library that could be told about a remote CouchDB instance. Oh well, perhaps in the future sometime.

Comment: Indeed, this has been happening in recent months! Check out my links to TouchDB in the update to my answer above.